# Constraints on Gmail signatures

Tags: gmail, html, email-signature

What are the constraints that Gmail puts on email signatures?

I'm trying to create a simple HTML table signature that users can copy and paste into Gmail's signature section, however I keep running into the "Sorry, the signature for [] is too long. Please try a shorter signature" error.

I'm aware of the 10,000 character limit, but the total HTML character count is much less than that.

If I delete a few of the images or some of the text from the signature I can get it to pass this constraint, however the signature is practically rubbish because of the deleted content.

I've tried to trial and error it to find a pattern to understand the rules, but nothing is emerging yet. Certainly, deleting big chunks of HTML from the signature has no effect.

So, does anyone know the restrictions (character, HTML, images, or otherwise) that Gmail is referring to when it throws this error?

Comment: Please accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Right, solved this one...

Problem was that I was copying the signature from within another page, and even though I wasn't copying any of the page's HTML directly, it would seem that something was getting dragged across in the pasting process.

So the solution was to create a new page with no other markup than the table to be used for the signature and make the copy and paste from there.